# Do Thrusters and Tracks work together

Tags: robocraft

According to the [wiki](http://robocraft.gamepedia.com/Caterpillar_Tracks#Placement_.26_Usage):

> In most cases, tank tracks should not be paired with any other movement type other than walker legs; their immense weight means that
> all other movement types will be severely overburdened, which
> decreases their top speed and renders the usage of them pointless.

But does this include thrusters?

- Thrusters pointing **down** (to lift) will be a bad combo, as anything with treads will be too heavy to "thruster jump"
- Thursters pointing **up**, (to push down) is likely redunant, this is normally useful to increase your weight and your traction, but tracks have plenty of both.

  This leaves:
- **Sideways** pointing thrusters, for turning faster
- **Forward/backwards** pointing thrusters for speed

Do these work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, actually... They do.

*But the differences are very subtle, that it's not worth it.*

---

## It's simply to do with physics.

Movement apparatuses are split into two categories:

- High Traction - Crawler Legs and Tank Tracks
- Low Traction - Hover, Wheels and Copter Blades

When a apparatus has high traction (in this case: Tank Tracks), most of the forward force comes from the moving apparatus. This means that if the Tank Tracks were to stop, all acceleration would drop to 0 as the friction instantly stops it.

#### But wait! What about thrusters reliving some of the force?

Yes, the thrusters do relief some of the force required to move your robot (providing it's facing forward/back) thus gaining you a little more speed.
Except, due to the immense weight of the Tank Tracks, the thrusters do not do much.

#### So how about sideways?

Well, this is a common misconception, most easily demonstrated with the use of copters or hovers.
As you know, A and D turns your vehicle (rotates around a point) rather than strafe.

The strafing effect is due to the thrusters throwing you in the direction they're pointed in; it's like how Hovers keep you afloat (a downward thrust).
Since Tank Tracks are on the ground, the strafing effect does not exist as most of the friction from the ground stops it from moving sideways (as opposed to low friction in the air) due to its high traction... and weight.

Comment: Actually thrusters with tank tracks or walker legs don't increase speed at all, they just allow the vehicle to accelerate faster.